# Collision without physics (Cocos2D + Box2D iOS)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, listener, box2d, contacts

I'm a beginner in the Cocos2D world, and even more in Box2D's. I'm developing an iOS game with these two engines, and what I want, is to have a guy (hero) to pick up coins in a scrolling map.

Well, the problem is the "Contact Listener". I can't seem to understand what it really does, and how I can use it to make the difference between my coins and other bodies (that are all static bodies) around the map.
I set all the coins `.isSensor = true` to disable collisions. I'm using *MyContactListener* from raywenderlich.com tutorial.

So, the main question is: How to know what type of body is in collision with the hero's body through the contact listener?

(i've read many tutorials and questions on here and I can't seem to know where to begin)

Thanks!

Edit:

Si, I finally got it to work with sprite.tag, but I can't destroy the bodies and the textures. Sometimes when using `[textureB removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];` I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
And as I understood, I can't destroy the body since I'm actually using it.

But when trying to use `body->SetUserData(self);` in my Hero class

```
@interface Hero : CCNode {
CCSprite * texture;
CGPoint position;
b2Body* body;
TypeCase type;
}
```

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in my update method:

```
for(b2Body *b = world_->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        if ([b->GetUserData() isKindOfClass:[Hero class]])
        {
            Hero* hero = (Hero*)b->GetUserData();
            CCSprite *heroSprite = hero.texture;
            heroSprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        }
        else if ([b->GetUserData() isKindOfClass:[Tile class]])
        {
            Tile* tile = (Tile*)b->GetUserData();
            CCSprite *tileSprite = tile.texture;
            tileSprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        }       
    }
}
```

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling isKindOfClass.

**Hero userData**

```
b2BodyDef heroBodyDef;
heroBodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
heroBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
heroBodyDef.position.Set(position.x/PTM_RATIO, position.y/PTM_RATIO);
body = world_->CreateBody(&heroBodyDef);
body->SetUserData(self);
```

**Tile userData**

```
b2BodyDef blockBodyDef;
blockBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
blockBodyDef.position.Set(position.x/PTM_RATIO, position.y/PTM_RATIO);
blockBodyDef.userData = self;
b2Body *body = world ->CreateBody(&blockBodyDef);
```

Comment: Why isKindOfClass is not working for you ? and in what line do you get the exception ?

Comment: I edited the update method: I get the exception when isKindOfClass is called.

Comment: It seems like the data is released somewhere before you access it. Can you post the code where you allocate the body user data ? do you use ARC in your project ?

Comment: I edited with the userData allocation. I don't use ARC.

Comment: I need to see where you allocate (with [hero alloc]) and where you release your hero object that you pass to userData. I believe you release your hero instance and therefore when trying to access it from the body object it is already deallocated

Comment: I allocate it in the init method of my game scene and release it in the dealloc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35365/discussion-between-thegameg-and-giorashc)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use physics objects for coins.. this will affect on fps :)
create CCSprite for coins and detect collisions with coin sprite and body->UserData;
Add your coins in CCArray and write something like this in your update method:

```
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)yourObject.body->GetUserData();
Coins *coinObject;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(coinsArray, coinObject)
   {
     if (CGRectIntersectsRect([sprite boundingBox], [coinObject boundingBox]))
       {
         // collision detected;
       }
   }
```

if you want to use physics body for your coins, you need to create typedef for yourObject states, and in your contact listener `void ContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact)` method change yourObject currentState. currentState is yourObject's property.
Do something like this in `void ContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact)`

```
yourObject.currentState = isCollideOnCoin;
```

and after this in your update add this line:

```
if (yourObject.currentState == isCollideOnCoin)
{
 // collision detected;
}
```

Comment: In the first method, at each update I'm actually checking if my hero is touching every single coin of the array, right? Is this what the ContactListener is doing but with bodies instead of sprites?

Comment: Yes first method works that way and I always use it. ContactListener uses callbacks, for more info u can check this tutorial http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom class (say `BodyType`) which indicates bodies type (in your case player/coin)

then you can use the user data property on your created bodies :

```
playerBody->SetUserData(new BodyType(1));
coinBody->SetUserData(new BodyType(2));
```

In the contact listener there is a method named `beginContact` which has an argument of type `b2Contact*` named `contact`.

Use this argument to get the two bodies :

```
b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
```

then you can know if your player hit a coin by checking :

```
if ((bodyA->GetUserData().getType() == 1 && bodyB->GetUserData().getType() == 2) ||
    (bodyA->GetUserData().getType() == 2 && bodyB->GetUserData().getType() == 1)) {
   // Mark collision or save coin body in a member of your contact listener for removing it later
}
```

- Of course make sure the user data is not null as all bodies will be passed to the contact listener and not all might have the user data member set.

**EDIT**

Regarding the BAD_ACCESS do the following :

```
 if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
     id myUserData = (id)b->GetUserData();

     if ([myUserData isKindOfClass:[Hero class]])
     { 
        Hero *hero = (Hero *)myUserData;
        // Do your stuff
     }
 }
```

Comment: I start to understand this, but I have one problem. The userdata for my bodies is their texture. Is there any way to include the type as well?

Comment: Well you can create a wrapper class for both texture and body type... Since userData is a pointer to void you have endless of options :)

Comment: I have a hero class, and I'm setting `body->SetUserData(self);` but it seems like it is casting it wrong since all the fields are wrong.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the relevant code ? what do you mean by all fields are wrong ?